# replace all '/' with '\/' in bash/shell script

Tags: bash, shell

This might be very simple but I am stuck at getting this done in shell/bash.
I have input like "`a/b/c/d`" and I want to replace all '`/`' with '`\/`' and the output would be 'a/b/c/d'

another example is `12.12.12.12/32`  >>> `12.12.12.12\/32`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Currently, your question is not legible or comprehensible. Please use the formatting tools to show raw characters. For starters, you could put the example parts between backticks `\`...\``

Comment: I've edited the question to make backslashes visible (as @chryss suggested) -- if this is not what's intended, please revert the edit.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's not to make it acceptable to `sed` is it?

Comment: exactly, I need it just to make 'sed' acceptable...is there any other way around then probably I do not need replace at all?

Comment: Yes, use another delimiter, e.g. `sed "s#$foo#$bar#g"`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `bash`'s parameter expansion:

```
$ input="a/b/c/d"
$ echo "${input//\//\\/}"
a\/b\/c\/d
```

Given a variable `input`, `${input//xxx/yyy}` yields the content of `input` with every `xxx` replaced with `yyy`. Here `xxx` is `\/` (`/` must be escaped to not be mixed up with the next `/`) and `yyy` is `\\/` (`\/` with `\` being escaped).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you access the text or strings you want to make the replacement in, something like this might work. You have to escape both `/` and `\` inside the sed command.

```
var='a/b/c/d'
echo "$var" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

Comment: `echo "$var"`, not `echo $var`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). If the user's input were `* / * / 3 / 4`, leaving the expansion unquoted would result in output containing a list of files.

Comment: OK, fair enough, for style reasons. I've made the change. However, I don't for a second expect that part to be relevant to the OP's script - I just added it to have something to hang the sed command on, and given I provided the input, I control it.

Comment: If we're a teaching resource, it's important to demonstrate practices that are safe to apply broadly. Part of why the ABS is considered such a poor resource in the bash community isn't so much outright inaccuracies (though there are a few) as examples that showcase unsafe practices; those practices tend to get copied and applied, even when their presence is only incidental, leading to people who learned from the ABS writing bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash only

```
var='a/b/c/d'
echo "${var//\//\\/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

```
echo "12.12.12.12/32" |sed 's,/,\\/,g'
```

Output:

```
12.12.12.12\/32
```

In such scenarios, use a delimiter other than `/`, as i used `,` in the above example. You can use for example: `#`,`?`....etc